# How to open "index.html#page1" local link in UIWebView?

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, url, webview

I have used the following code for open local HTML file in my web view

```
NSString *htmlFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"index" ofType:@"html"];
NSString* htmlString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:htmlFile encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
[webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];
```

But now I want to open **"index.html#page1"** type of HTML link. Where "index.html" is the main HTML file and **"#page1"** is the div id on same HTML file. Like

```
<div data-role="page" id="page1"></div>
```

How can I use this type of HTML link on my WebView??

Comment: A possible (didn't test), `htmlFile` is the path for your file, so you may be able to use it and instead of loading the `htmlString` and load the URL instead from the path.